# Image plotted with matplotlib not showing colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a .fit file. I have read the file, displayed the image with scale. When I want to write this image in .png file, the .png file is displaying the image without scale. I am attaching the code that I have tried.

```
import pyfits
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

hdulist = pyfits.open('HMI20170425_134641_6173.fits')
image_data = hdulist[0].data
hdulist.close()
fig=plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
fig.write_png('image.png')
```

It is showing output image with scale. However, the 'image.png' file showing image without scale.
Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you call the *scale* is actually the colorbar ? Which indeed is missing when you use `fig.write_png` because here you are saving only the image part of the plot. You should use [`plt.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) instead:

```py
# use astropy instead of pyfits which is no more maintained
import astropy.io.fits as pyfits 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

image_data = pyfits.getdata('HMI20170425_134641_6173.fits')
plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('image.png')
```